# For server side pixel tracking getting only event don't get any parameter through tag manager

Tags: laravel, google-tag-manager, pixel

I have configured browser and server-side tracking through Tag Manager and Pixel for my Laravel-based website. While the browser-side tracking is working correctly, I am not receiving any parameters on the Pixel for server-side tracking. I've implemented Stape and GA4 for the server-side configuration. Could someone please assist me in resolving this issue? Your guidance is much appreciated.

I have tried to find the solution but couldn't find event can't identify where could be the issue.

Comment: What does Stape support say?